# Django REST framework no authentication details

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am building out an API using Django rest framework, but I am having trouble authenticating a request using basic authentication. For testing purposes I have a view that, when called via `POST` and provided with a valid username/password for a `User` model, should return that model with the provided `id`, in this case `id=1018`

```
curl -X POST http://<my-url>/api/detail/1018 -u <username>:<password>
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

`GET` requests work fine as no authentication is required. I have been roughly following the [rest framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions). In each class I have `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)`

And in `permissions.py`

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the account.
        # I have commented this out and set it to return True so that I can test
        # more easily narrow down the cause of the error.
        #obj.owner.id == request.user.id
        return True
```

I'm not even sure if it is a code issue, as it says that credentials were not provided, not that the credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after digging deeper into the docs, I found a caveat when deploying with Apache. [Turns out you have to add a line to your httpd.conf file.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration)